tight lower bound on square root difference
Let $a,a',b,b', \alpha \in [0,1]$
and
$$\mu = \frac{1+ 2 (1-2 \alpha) a +\sqrt{4 a (a - 2 \alpha +1) - 8 (1- \alpha)b +1}}{4 \alpha(1 - \alpha)} $$
$$\mu' = \frac{1+ 2 (1-2 \alpha) a' +\sqrt{4 a' (a' - 2 \alpha +1) - 8 (1- \alpha)b' +1}}{4 \alpha(1 - \alpha)} $$
what is a tight lower bound on $\mu' - \mu$ in terms of $a'-a$ and $b'-b$

To help with the calculus, one may think of upper bounding the denominator in the last equation:
$$\mu' - \mu =   \frac{ (1-2 \alpha)}{2 \alpha(1-\alpha)} (a'-a) +\frac{\sqrt{4 a' (a' - 2 \alpha +1) - 8 (1- \alpha)b' +1}- \sqrt{4 a (a - 2 \alpha +1) - 8 (1- \alpha)b +1}}{4 \alpha(1 - \alpha)}$$
$$=   \frac{ (1-2 \alpha)}{2 \alpha(1-\alpha)} (a'-a) +\frac{4 (a'^2 - a^2) +4(1-2\alpha)(a'-a) -8(1-\alpha)(b'-b)}{4 \alpha(1 - \alpha)(\sqrt{4 a' (a' - 2 \alpha +1) - 8 (1- \alpha)b' +1}+ \sqrt{4 a (a - 2 \alpha +1) - 8 (1- \alpha)b +1})}$$

e.g. $\sqrt{4 a' (a' - 2 \alpha +1) - 8 (1- \alpha)b' +1} \le \sqrt{4 (1 + 1) +1}$. You can obtain better bound.
